# How to pass Pentaho user to BIRT report?

Tags: parameters, birt, pentaho

I integrated BIRT viewer on Pentaho BI Server and i would like to know how to pass the Pentaho username to Birt to filter the report data. I've read about pass it through an Xaction, other suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on security requirements,  you could pass the username or some form of it in the report url as a report parameter and filter your dataset with it.

Comment: I know how to pass parameters via URL to BIRT Viewer, but not how and where Pentaho calls BIRT Viewer and add parameters to the URL; through an XAction maybe?

Comment: Finally done with an XAction redirecting to a customized URL that points to BIRT Viewer and passing parameters on it.